# Microsoft SQL Calculating Backlog

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to calculate the backlog for every week in the past month. Date format is in (MM/DD/YY)

```
| mutation | issued_date | queryno_i | status |
-----------------------------------------------
  01/05/14   12/31/13       321         OPEN
  01/02/14   08/01/13       323         CLOSED
  01/01/14   06/06/13       123         OPEN
  01/01/14   01/01/14       1240        CLOSED
  01/02/14   01/01/14       1233        OPEN
  01/03/14   01/03/14       200         CLOSED
  01/05/14   01/04/14       300         OPEN
  01/06/14   01/05/14       231         OPEN
  01/07/14   01/06/14       232         CLOSED
  01/09/14   01/10/14       332         OPEN
  01/11/14   01/11/14       224         CLOSED
  01/15/14   01/14/14       225         CLOSED
  01/16/14   01/15/14       223         OPEN
```

I want my result set to look like this:

```
WeekNum | Opened | Closed | Total Open
--------------------------------------
   1        4        3         4    <= (2-4)+ data in week 2 so (2-4)+(1-2)+7
   2        4        2         6    <= (1-2)+7           
   3        2        1         7    <= total count
```

My Code is below however I am not sure how to query the last part. I am not even sure if this is possible or not.

```
WITH 
issued_queries AS
(
     SELECT DATEPART(wk, issued_date) AS 'week_number'
           ,COUNT(queryno_i) AS 'opened'
     FROM t.tech_query
     WHERE DATEADD(D,-12,issued_date) > GETDATE()-40
     GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, issued_date)
),
closed_queries AS
(
    SELECT DATEPART(wk, mutation) AS 'week_number'
          ,COUNT(queryno_i) AS 'closed'
    FROM t.tech_query
    WHERE status=3 AND DATEADD(D,-12,issued_date) > GETDATE()-40
    GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, mutation)
),
total as
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total'
    FROM t.tech_query
    WHERE status!='3'
)

SELECT issued_queries.week_number
     , issued_queries.opened
     , closed_queries.closed
FROM issued_queries JOIN closed_queries
  ON (issued_queries.week_number = closed_queries.week_number)
  ORDER BY week_number
```

Comment: it is not clear how the last column is calculated. Can you clarify?

Comment: How I would like to calculate the last column is to count all records that are OPEN then work backwards from there by calculating open - closed for the week and subtracting with this number from the total open. so for week 2 with total of 100 open and week 1 with 20 closed and 10 open I would have week 2 with total open=90. Do you think this is possible to achieve within SQL? I hope this make sense..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backlog for every week in the past month.
I've taken this to mean last 4 weeks, as that appears to be what you are doing.
Assuming "mutation" represents the date a record was updated (maybe set to closed).

So first, I generate a list of dates, so that way there will be an answer for week number X even if there are no new/closed records.

```
declare @SundayJustGone datetime

-- We need to get rid of the time component, done through convert.
set @SundayJustGone = convert(date, dateadd(d, 1-DATEPART(dw, getdate()), getdate()))
-- If earlier than sql 2008, can get rid of time component through: set @SundayJustGone = SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @SundayJustGone))

;with 
Last4Weeks as
(
-- Get the sunday of the week just gone.
select @SundayJustGone as SundayDate -- Sunday just gone

union all

select dateadd(d, -7, SundayDate) -- Get the previous Sunday
from Last4Weeks
where dateadd(d, -7, SundayDate) > dateadd(Wk, -4, @SundayJustGone) -- where the new date is not more than 4 weeks old
)
select A.SundayDate, 
    DATEPART(wk, DateAdd(d, -1, A.SundayDate)) as Week_Number, -- SQL considers Sunday the first day of the week, so we need to move it back 1 day to get the right week
    (select count(*) 
        from t.tech_query 
        where issued_date between DateAdd(d, -6, A.SundayDate) and A.SundayDate -- Was issued this week. (between monday - sunday)
        ) as Opened,
    (select count(*) 
        from t.tech_query 
        where status = 3 -- where it is closed
        and mutation between DateAdd(d, -6, A.SundayDate) and A.SundayDate -- and the mutation was this week. (between monday - sunday)
        ) as Closed,
    (select count(*) 
        from t.tech_query 
        where (status != 3 or datediff(d, mutation, A.SundayDate) < 0 ) -- Is still open, or was closed after this week.
        and datediff(d, issued_date, A.SundayDate) >= 0 -- and it was issued on or before the sunday.
    ) as TotalOpen
from Last4Weeks as A
```

hopefully this helps.

the results are different to yours, as I assume Monday is the first day of the week. To change start of week back to sunday, saturday needs to be considered end of week, so, change the `set @SundayJustGone = convert(date, dateadd(d, 1-DATEPART(dw, getdate()), getdate()))` to `set @SundayJustGone = convert(date, dateadd(d, -DATEPART(dw, getdate()), getdate()))` (1 removed)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Took me some time to understand everything but everything makes sense to me!!